# Is it possible to create a matplotlib barplot of timed values using simple notation?

Tags: matplotlib

Is the DataFrame['2002':'2005'][['Value1','Value2']].bar(any args?) possible way to create a bar plot of Dataframe, where 2 values are distributed within a long period of time. 
I can create a simple plot, but I want bars (1 bar - 1 day).
If there is no such a simple way, what would be the simpliest one?

Comment: What do you mean by distributed? You have only 2 values, right? Do you want pandas to interpolate between these two values and plot a bar every day, changing from day to day a little so that the last one finally equals value2? Please clarify. Please post `df.head()` to show the structure of your dataframe. Please post the code of your attempt and why the result is not that what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: No, I simply want to get a plot of two different timeseries (for example mean daily temperature and mean daily pressure), drawn on one plot as bars.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not *too* self coding, but anyway, possible, so it works... (thanks to these [guys](https://scentellegher.github.io/programming/2017/05/24/pandas-bar-plot-with-formatted-dates.html) here...)

Suppose you have a dataframe like

```
df.head()
            temperature     pressure
2018-10-01    21.860016  1031.418143
2018-10-02    20.590761  1063.008550
2018-10-03    21.356381  1047.183300
2018-10-04    20.393329  1037.710172
2018-10-05    20.716377  1027.680324 
...           ...        ...
```

Then you'd need to import

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
```

to plot your data like

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis_date()

ax.bar(df.index -md.num2timedelta(.2), df.temperature, .4, color='r', label = df.temperature.name)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.bar(df.index  +md.num2timedelta(.2), df.pressure, .4, color='b', label = df.pressure.name)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%b %d'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.WeekdayLocator())

fig.legend()
```

Result:

[image]